# foreach function to create array from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

need to return an array like this for example:

```
 array(30 => 'Mercedes Benz 310 ',26 => 'Lamborghini Murcielago')
```

I have a database set up something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `car_name` tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  owner varchar(20) NOT NULL default ''
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

The `id` need to be the `array key`.

So I tried to use `foreach`, but I have still not quite understood how it works.

```
$q = "select `id`, `car_name` from `cars` where `owner`='$username'";
$result = $conn->query($q); 
unset($q); 

if( !$result){
    return array(0 => 'error'); 
}

$garage = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
$car_id = $garage["id"];
$car_name = $garage["car_name"]; 



foreach( $car_name as $key => $car_id ){

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't far off.  Something like this should give you the kind of array you're looking for.

```
    $q = "select `id`, `car_name` from `cars` where `owner`='$username'";
    $result = $conn->query($q); 
    unset($q); 

    if( !$result){
        return array(0 => 'error'); 
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $garage[$row['id']] = $row['car_name'];
    }

return $garage;
```